# Why specify a host when creating a socket server in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

When setting up a server socket in Python, the `socket.bind(address)` method allows you to specify the address as a tuple like `(host, port)`. However, [the first example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) shows that you can specify the host as `''` as a shortcut to mean all interfaces (IPv4).

I can see how it could be useful to limit which interfaces a server socket listens on for the purposes of security. However, is there any other reason why you'd want to specify a host/IP address?

The reason for me asking is that I maintain a debugger interface written in Python. Someone has asked me why I don't just use `''` as the host, so that remote clients can connect without any config change. This doesn't feel right somehow, but felt like a more technical explanation would be necessary!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious example is the case of running a service on a multihomed machine.

Maybe you want a different key for the sshd on each ip address.

Or totally different web servers all listening on port 80 but different addresses.

You get the idea.

I can't see why it would be necessary in your case unless you want multiple instances of the debugger running or to limit connections to localhost for example.